# A rule to calculate efficiency for a thermodynamic cycle.

Tags: thermodynamics

I am studying for a test on thermodynamics and a problem that is frequently asked is to calculate the efficiency of a thermodynamic cycle (on the P-V) diagram.

So I have come with a following rule, which seems to work although I am sure how to prove it completely.

First I identify whether the given cycle represents a heat engine or a refrigerator. This is easy, one could look at the total work done over a cycle. If it is negative then we can say that we are extracting work from the gas and so it is a heat engine. We could also deduce this by looking at the cycle and checking whether it is clockwise or anti-clockwise.

Once we have done that, we get two cases. If it is a heat engine then we want work and we pay by giving heat. So $$\eta=\frac{|W_{\text{cycle}}|}{\text{Sum of all the positive Q in the cycle.}}$$

For the refrigerator, we have that $$\eta=\frac{|Q_{\text{cycle}}|}{\text{Sum of all positive Work}}$$

Does this rule hold good for thermodynamic problems involving cycles on the P-V diagram?

Comment: It is correct for the engine. On the other hand, for the refrigerator we want it to extract as much heat as possible from the cold source at a small cost in the form of work. Hence the appropriate definition for the refrigerator efficiency is $\eta=|Q_2|/|W|$, where $Q_2$ is the heat exchanged with the cold reservoir.